# Execution failed for task ':google_api_headers:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

After updating to Dart 3.0 I have this error when I launch the app on Android simulator.
For iOS physical device its building ok. Unfortunately can't try with Android physical device. Any ideas?

```
e: /Users/amarchuk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_api_headers-1.2.0+1/android/src/main/kotlin/io/github/zeshuaro/google_api_headers/GoogleApiHeadersPlugin.kt: (52, 68): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
e: /Users/amarchuk/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_api_headers-1.2.0+1/android/src/main/kotlin/io/github/zeshuaro/google_api_headers/GoogleApiHeadersPlugin.kt: (58, 68): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_api_headers:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
2

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited
```

Comment: this is a bug and the issues is under Flutter Team review on Git
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103618

Answer (score 1):

as a temporarily solutions

1. Downgrade from Flutter 3.0

```
    flutter downgrade 2.10.5
```

2. open the file producing error GoogleApiHeadersPlugin.kt (cmd + click on it in console for macOS)
   and cut all the try catch part

```
    try {
                val info: PackageInfo
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    info = context!!.packageManager.getPackageInfo(call.arguments<String>(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES)
                    for (signature in info.signingInfo.apkContentsSigners) {
                        parseSignature(signature, result)
                    }
                } else {
                    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                    info = context!!.packageManager.getPackageInfo(call.arguments<String>(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
                    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                    for (signature in info.signatures) {
                        parseSignature(signature, result)
                    }
                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                result.error("ERROR", e.toString(), null)
            }
```

so if method is empty and doing nothing

```
if (call.method == "getSigningCertSha1") {}
```

I don't have enough knowledge to say what are the consequences of this but my app is working and all the google APIs are working too (google maps, google sign in, Firebase)

I suggest you save the deleted code somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

upgrading all Firebase plugins solves the issue. For the date of this answer latest versions are:

```
cloud_firestore to 3.1.15   
firebase_auth to 3.3.18   
firebase_core to 1.17.0   
firebase_crashlytics to 2.8.0    
firebase_messaging to 11.4.0   
firebase_remote_config to 2.0.7    
firebase_storage to 10.2.16
```

Comment: didn't solve the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

1. Upgrade packages in *pubspec.yaml*.
2. Change compileSdkVersion to 32 in *android/app/build.gradle*

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `flutter_google_places` in my project. I had to override the `google_api_headers` dependency.

```
    dependency_overrides:
      google_api_headers: ^1.3.0-dev.0
```

I also cut out the try-catch section in the error-producing file *GoogleApiHeadersPlugin.kt*